# A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor. Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
const homeScreenItems = [
  FeedScreen(),
  SearchScreen(),
  AddPostScreen(),
  Text('notification'),
  ProfileScreen(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid),
];
```

above code is my global variable page.
I want to pass uid I stored in Firestore to ProfileScreen() but I am getting the above titled error i.e **A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor. Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'.**

I have declared uid as final in my ProfileScreen() but still I am getting the above error

//here is the code of ProfileScreen()

```
class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;
  const ProfileScreen({Key? key,required this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  var userData = {};
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserData();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUserData() async {
    try {
      var snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(widget.uid)
          .get();
      setState(() {
        userData = snap.data()!;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      showSnakBar(e.toString(), context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        title: Text(userData['name']),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 40,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1647185255712-b5b8687b2a25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1722&q=80',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            children: [
                              buildStatColumn(20, 'posts'),
                              buildStatColumn(150, 'followers'),
                              buildStatColumn(10, 'following'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              FollowButton(
                                backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
                                borderColor: Colors.grey,
                                text: 'Edit Profile',
                                textColor: primaryColor,
                                function: () {},
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                    child: Text(
                      'username',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
                    child: Text('some bio'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Column buildStatColumn(int num, String lable) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          num.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
          child: Text(
            lable,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `const` before your `homeScreenItems ` list, because you can't assign dynamic values while using `const`.

Comment: Thanks it actually worked.Adding const in early stages of the code is really pain

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're using `const` in homeScreenItems - this sets the [variable constant](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) during compile-time and can't be changed. It's usually used for fixed values like Text widgets with fixed String values.

Also, utilizing the [bang (!) operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) doesn't guarantee that the value won't be null. This only assures the compiler that the value is not null.

Depending on your use-case, you can remove the `const` from homeScreenItems and add `ProfileScreen()` once the user has signed-in and you're able to fetch `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`.

```dart
List homeScreenItems = [
  FeedScreen(),
  SearchScreen(),
  AddPostScreen(),
  Text('notification'),  
];

...

if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null){
  homeScreenItems.add(ProfileScreen(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `List<Widget>`  instead of `const` like this

```
List<Widget> homeScreenItems = [...];
```